# how cancel label edit with escape key and return the label to what it was

Tags: c#, winforms, events, label

In Windows Form controls like listview and treeview, when someone edit the label of an item an then press the "Escape" key, the edition end but the node remains with whatever i write in it. I want in exchange that when i press the Escape key the label return to what it was. I know that i must take the label before the label edit precisely in the "BeforeLabelEdit" event. In the "KeyPress" event handler i don't know how to stop the label edition. How can i do that?

**Update**

i found the method that i thought that doesn't exist, but now the problem is other. The Escape key press appears to be unchatchable in the middle of an edition label action.

```
private void ObjectWithItems_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            if (treeViewDocXml.SelectedNode != null)
            {
                treeViewDocXml.SelectedNode.EndEdit(true);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: It already works this way by default, pressing Escape while editing the node restores the old text.  Both for TreeView and ListView.  I'd have to guess that you are messing this up in your event handler.  Can't tell, you forgot to paste a code snippet.

Comment: Hi @Hans perhaps my attemps to reproduce the problem i'm not having success. I even remove the association with the event handlers for Before and After edit label events and for my surprise the bad behaviour remains.  Do you know a way to grab a key press in the middle of a edition action?, to find a way to overcome my problem

Comment: @Hans another symptom of the problem is that when i press the Escape key it release the focus of the control. Could be the origin of the problem where the control is embedded ?....This control is embedded in a ToolWindow that is part of a VSPackage extension. In that context the focus leave the toolwindow and return to the IDE. This is complete different from the normal cancel of the label edition maintaining the focus and the selection of the edited item that one normally see in a free form.

Comment: Yeah, that would certainly cause this problem.  The Escape and Enter key are often handled at the message loop level, commonly to close a dialog.  Which would prevent it from reaching the temporary edit box inside the treeview.  A focus loss then ends the label edit, without a cancel.  Implementing the KeyDown event for the treeview doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

ok, I'am not sure what you talking about, but here is example how to cancel text box editing and set text before editing started:

```
 string textBefore;
 private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     textBefore = textBox1.Text;
 }

 private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
     if(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Escape)
         textBox1.Text = textBefore;
 }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi @Reniuz, the situation is different. Look for controls that have labels in their items like the both that i mention in the question. For those controls, the problem is how can i stop the label edition?, the keypress argument don't offers me any method or property to do that, or at least i don't see them till now. By default the "Escape" key do that, it stop the edition, but i wan't to modify the consequence of the cancelling action.

Comment: @voodoomsr: I doubt that WinForms event model offer any cancellable event to edit a label (with CancelEventArgs), like ASP.NET does

Comment: @voodoomsr: and why can't you use KeyPress event / Keys.Escape code?

Comment: hi @abatishchev  i found the method that i thought that doesn't exist, the EndEdit(). Now i have other problem, it just simply ignore the Escape key press. Is like his function can not be modified.

Comment: @voodoomsr Like  Hans Passant sayed if you just want to cancel your edition, escape key do it by default. Or do you want to do smth different on escape key pressed?